# multiple external javascript files- how to call function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have multiple external javascript files linked to my html page and want to call a function in one of them. Right now I'm doing onClick = "func()", but it's not calling the function. I'm trying to figure out the problem.....Do I need to specify which script the function is in? If so, how do I do that?
Thanks.

Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
...

<li id="tab"><span onClick = "get_code('tabOne')">Tab</span></li>
...
```

In file1.js:

```
function get_code(str)
{
    alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant JavaScript and HTML?

Answer (score 1):

By not working, do you mean that you do not get an alert box at all? or is the alert not displaying what you want?  If it's not displaying what you want, it could be because your code `alert(st);` is wrong, it should be `alert(str);`.

Comment: Interesting.. Are your .js files located in the same directory as the web page they are called from?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to copy the file.js function and paste it in `<HEAD>` section of HTML, does that work? Also, you should place `<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>` in the `<HEAD>` section of your HTML. Check for any variable name clashes. Also, in the alert function, you are passing `st` wherein it should be `str`. Make sure your Javascript path is correct. Right now, javascript files should be in the same directory.
How about trying out

```
<li id="tab" onClick="get_code('tabOne');">Tab</li>
```

Comment: @Piyysh The script links are in <HEAD>. onClick should work with the span tag, right?

Answer (score 1):

Do `onmouseover=""` or `onclick=""` show the dialog? Javascript is case-sensitiv.